# Solr 4.x and replicating collections

Tags: solr, solr4

I have 3 questions related to replicating collections in Solr4

1. Each Collection has own solrconfig.xml which has own replication setting and has to point into particular collection on master server. Is it possible to have only one global setting which will handle multiple collection?
2. If I will have 100 collections they will do 100 request every minute (or whatever the interval is) to the master server. Is it possible to make it work more clever and do only 1 request?
3. I need to create cores dynamically. One can add a collection though the admin panel (or script) but it requires collection directory with configuration already in place. Is there a way to create collections "on the fly" and replicate it to slave servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's very easy to achieve all of that with SolrCloud http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer to (1) and (2) is no, you can't. Collection is a logical configuration boundary.